# b-form-datepicker show only month and year

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have a `b-form-datepicker`. I want this b-form-datepicker to only select `month` and `year`. Is this possible ?

I couldn't find an example in `bootstrap-vue`.

Comment: BootstrapVue has no such component, you'd have to develop it yourself, using `<b-dropdown>` and your custom layout.

Answer (score 1):

After spend some time on this requirement, I came up with this work around solution. Please have a look and see if it can help you.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
      displayValue: '',
      selected: '',
      formattedStr: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onContext(ctx) {
      // The date formatted in the locale, or the `label-no-date-selected` string
      let formattedStr = ctx.selectedFormatted;
      const modifyFormattedStr = ctx.selectedFormatted.split(',').slice(1);
      const month = modifyFormattedStr[0].trim().split(' ').shift();
      const year = modifyFormattedStr[1];
      this.formattedStr = `${month}, ${year}`
      // The following will be an empty string until a valid date is entered
      this.selected = ctx.selectedYMD.split('-').slice(0, -1).join('-');
      this.displayValue = this.selected
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label for="example-input">Choose a date</label>
  <b-input-group>
    <b-form-input
                  id="example-input"
                  v-model="displayValue"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="YYYY-MM"
                  autocomplete="off"
                  ></b-form-input>
    <b-input-group-append>
      <b-form-datepicker
                         v-model="value"
                         button-only
                         right
                         locale="en-US"
                         aria-controls="example-input"
                         @context="onContext"
                         ></b-form-datepicker>
    </b-input-group-append>
  </b-input-group>
  <p class="mb-1">Selected: '{{ selected }}'</p>
  <p class="mb-1">Formatted String: '{{ formattedStr }}'</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mertcan Please do accept this answer if it helps you. So that it will be helpful for other fellow developers as well.